# Iterate nested map recursively in groovy jenkins

Tags: jenkins-groovy, nested-map

While iterating map I am getting error.
Followed with the below approach:

[How to iterate through all values of a nested map in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488434/how-to-iterate-through-all-values-of-a-nested-map-in-groovy)

def deNull(root) { if (root instanceof List) { root.collect { if (it instanceof Map) { deNull(it) } else if (it instanceof List) { deNull(it) } }
def map = [spring:[config:[activate:[on-profile:stage-release]]], test-property:stage]
map = deNull(map) println map.inspect()

Error:
startup failed: Script1.groovy: 9: illegal colon after argument expression;    solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized @ line 9, column 48.    :[config:[activate:[on-profile:stage-rel                                  ^ 1 error

I want output like below in key value pair.
on-profile=stage
test-property=stage

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- String values in Maps should be put in quotation marks
- keys in Maps containing special characters like `-` should also be put in quotation marks.
- The `deNull` method from your link iterates through the Map and replaces all the `null` values. I guess you're aiming to collect all the leaves of your tree.

Maybe that helps:

```
Map map = [spring:[config:[activate:["on-profile":"stage-release"]]], "test-property":"stage"]
List leaves = traverse(map)
assert leaves as String == "[on-profile=stage-release, test-property=stage]"

def traverse(root){
    if(root in Map){
        root.collectMany { (it.value in Map) ? traverse(it.value) : [it] }
    }else{
        root
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes correct I am trying to collect all the leaves in key-value pair format. I am reading yaml file and that is dynamic don't know the structure of yaml file. I am implementing rule validator same will executed while running pipeline.